# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError aacdecoder lib

Tags: android

I'm using an `aacdecoder` library with my application. I'm getting a

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ianmanda.starfmplus-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ianmanda.starfmplus-1/lib/arm64,
>   /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libaacdecoder.so"

and my main app module gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':libs')
}
```

and my module-lib gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

       ndk {
           abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips", "arm64"
       }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDir("src/main/libs")
        }
    }
```

Comment: library works fine with android <5 but anything above that gives error

Comment: Do you have a `libaacdecoder.so` in `src/main/libs/arm64`?

Comment: @DanielZolnai yes i have  libaaencoder.so in src/main/libs/arm64

Comment: See this medium post: https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d#.6jjy7x8lg 
Did you also add that line? `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
`

Comment: @DanielZolnai thanks that just solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the file `libaacdecoder.so` in `src/main/libs/arm64`, and added the line `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` to `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

solution is here [a mobiwise blog fixed it](https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d#.muipt0pg3)

thanks to @DanielZolnai